# SharePoint 2013 - Promoted Links - Remove / Customise Hover Animation

Tags: 2013, promoted-links

I know this question has been asked a number of times in different guises.

I am after a way of either removing the animation entirely so the link tile stays static instead of animating on hover or to limit the height of the animation.

I have removed the entire hover layer but doesn't then let me add text to the tile having to resort to creating tiles with writing within the image which is not ideal.

I am using SP 2013 on prem.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not satisfy you, as it doesn't remove the hover effect but hides the rolled up element - and as it also hides the title of the Tile:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".ms-tileview-tile-content a").css("visibility","hidden");
});
</script>
```

Embed this Code inside a Script Editor Webpart (or Content Editor Webpart) on the page.

According to another [forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d9156516-1298-48ae-8e31-c67eab56f786/i-want-to-remove-the-roll-over-effect-from-my-promoted-link?forum=sharepointdevelopment) also this should work (However, it didn't work for me - but I am using SharePoint Online - there might have been a change in the HTML-DOM):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName");
function myCustomFunctionName() {
    $(".ms-tileview-tile-content").off('mouseenter');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to hide the hover effect before but I then have to have the text of the tile within the tile image. Is there a way the hover effect can be disabled but the title of the tile still appear?

Or whether you can suggest another tile soultion?

Thanks

Comment: I honestly couldn't find in the HTML-DOM (with Webbrowser Dev-Tools) what causes the animation. I have tried different approaches, such as unbinding all event listeners from the tiles. But SharePoint's animation always remained :( I will give you an update, when I will find out anything else about it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an alternative I found on some other forum. It may not work, as there is a chance that the HTML-DOM of SP has changed since the answer is quite old.